# Добавить теги в строку

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Есть строка такого вида

```
"Параметр 1; Параметр 2; Параметр 3;"
```

Не подскажете как в нее добавить теги, должно получится вот так:

```
"<li>Параметр 1;</li><li>Параметр 2;</li><li>Параметр 3;</li>"
```

То есть, нужно добавить открывающий тег `li` в начале строки, закрыв `li` в конце строки и открывающий и закрывающий тег `li` после символа `;` если этот  символ не последний (там просто закрывающий тег `li`, открывающий уже не нужен)

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = str_replace("; ", ";</li><li>", $str);
$str = "<li>" . $str . "</li>";
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает!

Comment: Если ответ помог, то отметьте решением (галочка слева).

Answer (score 0):

Можно решить и с помощью регулярных выражений:

```
$str = 'Параметр 1; Параметр 2; Параметр 3;';

echo preg_replace('~(?<=\b|\s)(.+?;)\s?(?=\b|$)~u', '<li>$1</li>', $str);
```